# netty: save channel handler context for later use

Tags: java, netty

I would like to save an incoming channel (ctx) for later use, like in a HashMap.

```
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
        System.out.println("Server received: " + in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        // example channels.put("channelname", ctx);
    }
```

My idea behind is that I can get the ctx from the map by a string and write a message from another class to it like:

`channels.get("keyforchannel").writeAndFlush("here my message to this specific channel");`

Does anyone have an idea on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Netty provides the [ChannelGroup](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html) for this purpose.
It's not a map, but a thread-safe Set for indexing active Channels.
It has a number of useful features such as writing to all Channels in the group,  filtering which Channels you want to write to with a [ChannelMatcher](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelMatcher.html) and automatically ejecting Channels when they close.